# How to make text appear into a grid when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have made 2 buttons, `completeButton` and `cancelButton`. When the `completeButton` is clicked, I want it to display "Completed" under the column "Status". When the `cancelButton` is clicked, I want it to display "Cancelled" under the column "Status". I already have:

```
private void cancelButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

and

```
private void completeButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

But I don't know how to make the text appear in the grid. Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: This is ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

User specified it is asp .net related *this answer does not apply*

Grid is a container control you cannot edit "the inside" of a cell.
You have to add a TextBlock in the Grid placed in wherever you want and then change the TextBlock Text property

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you have button, you need to added for example Literal depending how you need to present the result.

In your aspx add some thing like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Complete" Text="Complete" runat="server" />
<asp:Literal ID="Msg1" Text="" runat="server" />
```

In your aspx.cs file add following:

```
this.Msg1.Text = "default text or leave empty";
Cancel.Click += new EventHandler(this.cancelButton_ServerClick);
Complete.Click += new EventHandler(this.completeButton_ServerClick);
```

And your existing method following changes:

```
private void cancelButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Msg1.Text = "Cancel";
}

private void completeButton_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Msg1.Text = "Complete";
}
```

So now each time we click on Cancel we chagne Msg1 to Cancel and the same for Complete.

Comment: Are you sure this is XAML? It was tagged `c#` `html`, so I assumed it was ASP.NET, maybe Web Forms.

Comment: It's ASP.NET, would I still do it the same way? @HereticMonkey

Comment: @Ale I think that's a better question for maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ, since he wrote the answer :).

Comment: @Ale here is my updated answer, looking forward to see how it goes with it.